# How to access increment value of session on same page in php

Tags: php

How to access the incremented value of session on the same page where we have defined the initial value of session, I am using this method for incrementation of value but on another page

```
<?php
    $_SESSION['indexValue'] = 1;
?>
```

This is my test.php page where i have decrelaed the inital value of session.

```
<?php
    $Incrementvalue = $_SESSION['indexValue'];
    $counter = (int)$Incrementvalue;
    if ($counter=$counter) { 
        $counter++;
        $_SESSION['indexValue'] = $counter;             
    }
    echo "$_SESSION['indexValue']";
?>
```

This is my getdata.php page where I have implmented the increment value function. Now i have to pass this increment value of Session again on test.php page . How can I perform this?

Comment: tagged `php` and `node.js`? seems odd to be running both on the server - and yet there's no javascript (browser or nodejs variety) in the question at all?

Answer (score 0):

your code seems not to be thought off

first of all, you need to call session_start() at beginning
then you can access everyewhere your $_SESSION variable (if you call session_start() before)

```
if ($counter=$counter) { 
      $counter++;
     $_SESSION['indexValue'] = $counter;             
}
```

this seems useless

```
$_SESSION['indexValue']++;
```

is enough

Comment: I have already session start() in my program but my concern is how to access  increment value on the test.php page

Comment: just access $_SESSION['indexValue']

the $_SESSION variable is accessable from every page which calls session_start() before

Comment: I have already session started () in my project on the top. basically, i am implementing load more through pagination API because of that I have to increment the value of test.php page on scrollbar

Comment: Can you understand my query

Comment: no i cant understand your problem.. just access $_SESSION['indexValue'] - thats all

Answer (score 0):

First of all there are few errors in code like

`if ($counter=$counter)` should be `if ($counter == $counter)`

And

`echo "$_SESSION['indexValue']"` should be `echo $_SESSION['indexValue']`.

Now answer to your question is that session is accessible anywhere throughout the project/application. So you need not to pass it , just access it as `$_SESSION['indexValue']`.

Comment: I am implementing load more that why I have increased the index value but starting from the    $_SESSION['indexValue'] = 1; but after that i want the incremented value on the same page